# How to add new line in FormattedString

Tags: xamarin

```
 public FormattedString FormattedDescription
 {
     get
     {
         return new FormattedString
         {
            Spans = 
            {
                new Span 
                { 
                    Text = RoleName, 
                    FontSize = 16, 
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold 
                },
                new Span 
                { 
                    Text = "/ " + ProjectRoleID + "/ "+Part + "/ "+Gender + "/ " + AgeRange
                },
           }
        };
    }
    set 
    { 
    }  
}
```

> In above code i want to Display RoleName in First line and other Detail in second Line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `Environment.NewLine` to move text to the next line like this:

```
   public FormattedString FormattedDescription
   {
       get
       {
           return new FormattedString
           {
                Spans = {
                            new Span { Text = RoleName, FontSize = 16, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold },
                            new Span { Text = Environment.NewLine, FontSize = 16 },
                            new Span { Text = "/ " + ProjectRoleID + "/ "+Part + "/ "+Gender + "/ " + AgeRange},
                        }
           };
       }
       set { }  
   }
```

Answer (score 57):

Here is a "Cleaner" Solution fully in XAML:

- First, add this namespace to your XAML: `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"`

This is the system namespace and it contain all system classes.

- Second, call the Environment.NewLine in XAML, in the Span you wish as shown bellow:

```xml
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="First Text"/>
            <Span Text=" "/>
            <Span Text="Second Text"/>
            <Span Text="{x:Static system:Environment.NewLine}"/>
            <Span Text="Above is a new line"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Here you have a clean way to show new lines.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this using XAML property element syntax:

```
 <Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span>
                <Span.Text>
Line 1
Line 2
                </Span.Text>
            </Span>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: You might use \r\n in XAML, the ASCII codes are: CR &#13; LF &#10; Also a custom label with a Replace method might work.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is bettter to use this one

```xml
     <StackLayout>
        <Label>
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString.Spans>
                    <Span Text="First Text"/>   
                </FormattedString.Spans>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
        <Label>
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString.Spans>
                    <Span Text="Above is a new line"/>
                </FormattedString.Spans>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
     </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What you are doing has nothing to do with adding new lines. Your "new line" comes from the default spacing of 10 DIP from the StackLayout. If Xamarin or Microsoft decide to alter the default spacing of a StackLayout, your "new line" label distance will also suffer. Furthermore it won't adapt its height when changing font or font size...

Comment: All that is needed is Spacing="0" and it doesn't matter what Xamarin or Microsoft do.

Comment: But the question was "How to add a new line in FormattedString" and his answer has nothing to do with that! Yes you can give it a spacing of "0" and it will kind of achieve maybe what has been requested but STILL it is off-topic!